# Remove last params from url

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove last params from the url for instance, i have url such as

http://localhost/autoservice/public_html/tickets/load_service/6

i want to get this result

http://localhost/autoservice/public_html/tickets

how to make this with jquery or javascript

i have tried many solutions by reading many post on stack but i can't get it right

```
 var url       = $(location).attr('href');
```

Comment: What is the rule to decide which are the "last parameters"? Remove the last 2 elements inside `/`? Everything after a given string i.e. "tickets"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this simple method using **[`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)** and **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**

```js
url = 'http://localhost/autoservice/public_html/tickets/load_service/6';
url = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
url = url.slice(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
alert(url);
```

Comment: i am Trying to vote up on for your answer but it says, in order to vote up ii must have 15 reputations. sound so bad

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex here:

```
^(.+)(\/[^\/]+\/.+)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aS9wD6/1)

Used with Javascript:

```js
var url = 'http://localhost/autoservice/public_html/tickets/load_service/6';

alert(
   'BEFORE\n' + url + '\n\n'+
   'AFTER\n' + url.replace(/^(.+)(\/[^\/]+\/.+)$/g, '$1')
);
```

Comment: thanks Stephan, what kinda function should i use with regex in this case. by the way i am not javascript coder. could you please guide me through this....

Comment: @ShareKnowledge I have added a javascript snippet for you ;)

Comment: Thanks Stephan, really appropriated your help